# What is energy-momentum tensor from interaction?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm confused while studying Weinberg's "Gravitation and Cosmology" chapter 12.

Action for collisionless plasma is

$I_M = -\sum\limits_n m_n \int dp \left[-g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx_n^\mu}{dp}\frac{dx_n^\nu}{dp}\right]^{1/2} - \frac{1}{4}\int d^4x \sqrt{g} F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}+\sum\limits_n e_n \int dp \frac{dx^\mu_n}{dp}A_\mu$

After that, text says that by calculating variation of action under metric variation,
$\delta I_M = \frac{1}{2} \sum m_n \int dp \left[-g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx_n^\mu}{dp}\frac{dx_n^\nu}{dp}\right]^{-1/2}\frac{dx_n^\lambda}{dp}\frac{dx_n^\kappa}{dp}\delta g_{\lambda \kappa} + \frac{1}{2}\int d^4 x g^{1/2} \left[F_{\mu}^{\; \lambda}F^{\mu \kappa} - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}\right]\delta g_{\lambda \kappa}$

I understood that two terms are right. But what I can't understand is why there is no contribution from $\sum\limits_n e_n \int dp \frac{dx_n^\mu}{dp}A_\mu$.

Under variation of metric, variation of this term is $\sum\limits_n e_n \int dp \frac{dx^\mu_n}{dp}A^{\nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}$.

I think, naively, this term should be included in energy momentum tensor, but adding this term makes divergence of energy momentum tensor weird, so I'm confused.

How can this term be eliminated in energy-momentum tensor?